How to Run Long-Running Tasks After Receiving Push Notification When App is Killed Using WorkManager?
I am working on an Android app where I need to execute a scheduled task after receiving a push notification, even when the app is killed. I am using Firebase data messages/payload to receive the notifications successfully in such scenarios.
The issue I am facing is that sometimes the processing initiated by the notification can take more than 10 seconds. I believe this lengthy processing is causing the service to get killed by the system.
From my research, it seems like WorkManager is a potential solution to handle this scenario. However, I have a few questions before implementing this approach:

Is it possible to use WorkManager to run tasks that may last for around 1 minute after receiving a push notification, even when the app is killed?

If using WorkManager is a viable solution, how can I properly schedule the work from within my FirebaseMessagingService to ensure it runs reliably?

Is WorkManager the best solution for this use case, or are there better approaches to ensure the long-running task completes after the app receives a notification?


Any guidance or sample code would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
